# Best ubuntu USB sound card with hardware acceleration of processing sound

Tags: drivers, usb, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

anyone knows if is it a sound card (USB) with hardware enhancements support under ubuntu? In my windows/MacOS I'm using a Creative cards (SB Omni, SB surround 5.1 pro) and there is a pretty good driver support of equalizer, crystalizer, bass redirection, surround effects etc.

I know that under ubuntu there are a software like pulseaudio-equalizer, but it always use a CPU, and of course add some delay to sound, so it isn't so good.
 There it is any card with some driver support of eq, etc under linux?

Comment: "best" is a matter of opinion.  Plus we have generic sound systems (alsa, pulseaudio); Linux is about using devices in a generic way (aka. 1 driver for 1 line of a chipset).  That might not be "the best" you are looking for.

Comment: Ubuntu studio is optimized for sound hands down

Comment: These Creative devices do all processing in the driver. I am not aware of any consumer USB audio device with hardware effects.

Comment: Yes, I know that the better solution is doing one driver per all devices. But this isn't possible in that way. Because all hardware are different and maybe it is possible make a generic driver, but if some hardware has a some better solutions, producent of this hardware should prepare own driver for this enhancements.

Comment: I'm not sure that everythings in Creative is made by windows driver. When I'm using a ubuntu pulseaudio-equalizer I'm getting a 10%-12% percent of CPU usage only for pulse with 100ms delay of sound (smaller buffer means cracking etc). When I'm using the same card in windows: I'm using equalizer, crystalizer, bas redirection, without any CPU usage, any delay (probably only ASIO delay = 5-10mc)

Comment: Creative windows drivers also use cpu and cause delay, but hidden in proprietary code. Pulseaudio does not compare to using windows ASIO drivers. Use JACK sound server if you want low latency. JACK has large selection of professional audio DSP packages